# Android: ZIP unpacking from base 64 encoded string

Tags: c#, android, soap, unzip, ksoap2

I've got problem with receiving a `.zip` file from C# SOAP web service. The file on server is correct (I can unpack it). I am sanding it as base 64 string, but when I convert it back in the Android app and try to unpack it, I'm getting

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 4294967295 but got 74274 bytes);

There is only one file in the `.zip`, and the code was working correctly on phones with android < 7.0.

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Here is my C# code to convert to base 64 string:

```
public static string FileToBase64String(string filename, string GUID)
{
    string output;
    try
    {
        byte[] AsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        output = Convert.ToBase64String(AsBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExceptionHandling.HandleError(e, "Zapis pliku " + filename + ". Metoda: [FileToBase64String]", GUID);
        //output = e.ToString();
        throw;
    }
    return output;
}
```

And here is my Android code:

```
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String result = response.toString();

            byte[] resultDecodedBase64Bytes = android.util.Base64.decode(result, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] newDBFileBytes = unZipDBFromBytes(resultDecodedBase64Bytes);


public byte[] unZipDBFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
    ZipInputStream zis = null;
    ZipEntry ze = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        boolean isDbFile = false;
        while (ze != null) {
            String fileName = ze.getName();
            if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(Engine.DATABASE_FILENAME)) {
                output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int data = 0;
                while ((data = zis.read()) != -1) {
                    output.write(data);
                }
                isDbFile = true;

            }
            if (isDbFile) {
                ze = null;

            }

        }

        if (output != null) {
            return output.toByteArray();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {

        try {
            if (zis != null) {
                zis.closeEntry();
                zis.close();
            }

            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (bis != null)
                bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Include your code in the question and format it, don't use external links.

Comment: Do you have all the updates for the phones.  It looks like the zip file in the header contains a size that is incorrect.  So it looks like the zip file is using a new version of zip then the phone.

Comment: Currently I am testing app on Phone with actual version of Android 7.0. All updates are installed.